# Nmap / Homebrew in Mac 10.12.2

Tags: macos, homebrew, nmap

I just installed successfully Homebrew in my Mac (Homebrew installs packages to their own directory and then symlinks their files into /usr/local.)n, but I can't run `nmap`

```
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:spring-boot-html-mail nunito$ brew help
Example usage:
  brew search [TEXT|/REGEX/]
  brew (info|home|options) [FORMULA...]
  brew install FORMULA...
  brew update
  brew upgrade [FORMULA...]
  brew uninstall FORMULA...
  brew list [FORMULA...]

Troubleshooting:
  brew config
  brew doctor
  brew install -vd FORMULA

Developers:
  brew create [URL [--no-fetch]]
  brew edit [FORMULA...]
  http://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook.html

Further help:
  man brew
  brew help [COMMAND]
  brew home
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:spring-boot-html-mail nunito$ nmap
-bash: nmap: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you specifically install nmap from brew? 
`brew install nmap`

Else it might be easier to just download nmap from their website then...

Answer (score 1):

Got same issue with zsh

`brew info nmap` will return you the `nmap` path, e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/nmap/7.93`

In your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile` add the following line

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/nmap/7.93/bin`

Then restart your terminal